# Info Node Eevee Integration

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, development

I am currently working on an integration for a length socket in the Hair Info node and got it working in cycles allready, but am currently struggling to find out where in the code the shader values get passed to Eevee.
Could someone take a look at the diff and help me out? :D

https://developer.blender.org/D10481

And the devtalk thread: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/hair-info-node-length/17661

Any help would be greatly appreciated!